# Merge two arrays when id in each array is of different type (string, number)

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using lodash, how can I merge two arrays by comparing ids when one array has the id as a string, and the other has the id as a number?

```
var a = [{
  id: 1,
  item: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  item: 2
}, {
  id: 3,
  item: 4
}];

var b = [{
  id: "1",
  profile: 1
}, {
  id: "2",
  profile: 2
}];
```

This is what I have tried. This works fine if the ids in both arrays are strings or both ids are numbers. Adding toString() or parseInt doesn't seem to work either.

```
return  _.map(a, function(obj) {
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(b, {
        id: obj.id
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing a custom function to the [`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) method?

```
return  _.map(a, function(obj) {
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(b, function(o) {
        return o.id == obj.id;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the ids for the resulting array all be numbers? The way you state, ids 1 and 2 are string, and id 3 is a number.

Comment: @JAck28 Sure.  Just assign the output of `_.assign()` to a variable and convert change the `id` value to string or int before returning it to `_.map()`: https://jsfiddle.net/ugL7z0oy/.

Answer (score 0):

```
const merged = _.reduce(a, (acc, obj) => {
    const match = _.find(b, val => obj.id == val.id);
    return match ? _.concat(acc, _.assign(obj, match)) : acc;
}, []);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f6ss8vau/

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge). It recursively merges arrays, and objects, and performs loose equality (==) to merge properties:

```js
var a = [{"id":1,"item":1},{"id":2,"item":2},{"id":3,"item":4}];

var b = [{"id":"1","profile":1},{"id":"2","profile":2}];

var result = _.merge([], a, b);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, looks like I was over-complicating things.